# Como executar uma query usando função no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, query, mariadb

Montei uma função que me conecta ao BD e me retorna uma consulta:

```
def consult(self, query):
    try:
        conn = mariadb.connect(
            user="XXXXX",
            password="XXXXX",
            host="192.168.000.000",
            port=3306,
            database="data_base"
        )
    except mariadb.Error as e:
        print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")

    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    return cur
```

E em uma outra função possui uma query que quero executar:

```
def query(self):

    stringQuery = """
    SELECT
    l.chave
    FROM inventario i
    INNER JOIN licencas l ON l.id = i.idLicenca
    WHERE i.id = 1728 
    """
    cur = self.consult(stringQuery)

    chave = str(cur)
    for y in ['\n', ',', '/', "'", '(', ')']:
        chave = chave.replace(y, "")
    
    print(chave)
```

Porém esse erro é retornado: '<mariadb.connection.cursor object at 0x0000028137FA59A0>'

Tentei modificar a função de execução, mas não obtive resultado.

Comment: Isso não é um erro, é o objeto de cursor que você recebeu como retorno. Para você obter os resultados desta consulta, precisará iterar sobre o cursor: `for row in cur: ...`

Comment: Nossa, deu certo. Não acredito que dei mole nisso. Valeu!!!